# How to access resources in Android Unittest?

Tags: android, unit-testing

My project has two projects:

```
main
mainTest
```

I created an "AndroidTestCase" in the "mainTest" and I tried to use **getContext().getResources()** to access the resources I created in the "mainTest" project. But I found the code is actually trying to get the resources in the "main" project. I think it is because when I use **getContext()** it returns an context representing the "main" project. But the **AndroidTestCase** class does not provide any methods to get its own resources.

P.S. I found I can directly use **class.getResourceAsStream()** to access the raw file, which is what I want. But still I hope there are more convenient way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can, from the application Context , request the resources from your test application.

```
protected Resources getResources(String packageName) throws NameNotFoundException {
    PackageManager pm = getContext().getPackageManager();
    return pm.getResourcesForApplication(packageName);
}
```

Comment: what if i want the package manager itself to point to the test app? i.e., i want to access the manifest of the test app?